move_base / teb_local_planner not subscribing to odometry/local message from robot_localization ekf_localization node
Currently building a autonomous mecanum drive robot with wheel encoders, IMU, and LiDAR (with GPS to be implemented using a global EKF later). The current configuration uses a local EKF from the robot_localization package to fuse sensor data, and teb_local_planner for local planning.
Below is the rqt_graph output (only using encoders with dummy input for testing off robot), displaying how the odometry/local topic generated by the robot_localization node isn't connected to move_base.

The published / subscribed topic has been remapped respectively when the robot_localization and move_base nodes are launched:
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_local" clear_params="true" >
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find jiqi_navigation)/config/robot_localization/ekf_local.yaml" />
  <!-- Remap publications -->
  <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/local" />
</node>

<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
  <rosparam file="$(find jiqi_navigation)/config/move_base/costmap_common_params.yaml"    command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
  <rosparam file="$(find jiqi_navigation)/config/move_base/costmap_common_params.yaml"    command="load" ns="local_costmap"  />
  <rosparam file="$(find jiqi_navigation)/config/move_base/local_costmap_params.yaml"     command="load" ns="local_costmap"  />
  <rosparam file="$(find jiqi_navigation)/config/move_base/global_costmap_params.yaml"    command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
  <rosparam file="$(find jiqi_navigation)/config/move_base/teb_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  <rosparam file="$(find jiqi_navigation)/config/move_base/move_base_params.yaml"         command="load" />
  <!-- Remap subscriptions -->
  <remap from="odom" to="odometry/local" />
  <!-- Remap publications -->
  <remap from="cmd_vel" to="cmd_vel" />
</node>

And the odometry topic has also been changed in the teb_local_planner_params.yaml config file:
TebLocalPlannerROS:

  odom_topic: odometry/local # Odometry topic name
  map_frame: odom # Change to map if using a static map

Is there any other issues that may be causing this disconnect between odometry/local and move_base?
Full config files can be found here: GitHub repository

For move_base itself, it won't subscribe to any topics to obtain that data, preferring to obtain the pose estimate of the robot by looking up transforms. The EKF publishes the odometry message and a transform, and move_base uses the latter.
As far as TEB, I'd recommend that you look at rosnode info as well. I'm not sure that the graph will show subscriptions with no publishers, and you may learn that move_base is still pointing at the wrong topic somehow, or that the TEB plugins is failing to load outright.
